# Указать память как свободную c#

Tags: c#, unity3d, сборщик-мусора

Скорее всего вопрос не новый, но найти ответ не смог. Есть ли в C# способ указать, чтобы принудительно освободить память используемую для переменной? Использую Unity и нужно достаточно часто создавать новые строковые переменные, а хранить их в памяти и ждать GC - не очень хорошая идея. Есть ли метод, чтобы указать что память этой переменной можно использовать.

Comment: `Есть ли метод, чтобы указать что память этой переменной можно использовать.` если у вас нет ссыллок на участок памяти, сборник сам догадается, что память можно освободить. Если вы хотите переиспользовать память, храните ваши строки в виде массива байт. Но это такое себе решение. Чтобы что то получше придумать, надо знать что вы делаете и какую задачу решаете.

Comment: GC не подходит. Он проверяет память только в определённые моменты, которые сам вычисляет, а мне нужно чётко указать, что данная ячейка памяти может использоваться, вне зависимости от наличия ссылок и т.д., что-нибудь из серии unsafe кода.

Comment: тогда вы зря приняли ответ, так как это `myVar = null;` только убирает ссылку на память, но не форсит очистку памяти. Сама пямять все такде будет освобождена когда GC решит её освободить.

Comment: Случайно нажал, не попал по кнопке downvote.

Comment: Вообще я видел методы класса Marshall, что-то для памяти было, но не видел, чтобы кто-то использовал это для явной очистки памяти.

Comment: перед тем, как лезть в эти дебри, сделайте замеры - насколько медленнее ваша программа работает? GC выделяет память очень быстро, потому вы должны убедиться, что вам надо именно это оптимизировать .

Answer (score 0):

Если есть необходимость часто создавать и освобождать в памяти что то - используйте структуры, они размещаются на стеке и производительность таких операций из-за этого выше.

Comment: Не подойдёт я использую конкретный класс string, и эту переменную нужно так-сказать удалять.

Comment: @Artromskiy, коротко: никак. Вы не можете сказать сборщику мусора: "Собери только этот объект" - пинать сборщик ради одного объекта просто нерационально. Так как Вы используете Unity, могу сказать, что подобная Ваша затея с единственным экземпляром string - экономия на спичках, так что если Вы наблюдаете просадки в производительности, воспользуйтесь профайлером и найдите реальные узкие места в Вашем коде. Так же можете, как Вам и советовали выше, использовать и переиспользовать массив символов вместо строки

Comment: Я имею ввиду не то чтобы сборщик собрал одну переменную, а чтобы с съёма CRL думала, что этот блок памяти можно использовать, что он свободен и память на этот указатель не нужна более.

Comment: Множество статей Unity по поводу того, что постоянное создание переменных любого типа приводит к большому скопление мусора и к тому, что GC в определённый момент должен будет остановить поток и очистить эту память, говорят, что оптимизация важна. Короче мне нужен unsafe код, чтобы освободить память переменной. Наверное это сравнимо с C++, но это достаточно важно.

Answer (score -2):

```
myVar = null; //Удаляем ссылку на память
GC.Collect(); //Принудительный сбор мусора
```

Comment: Более того, если переменная в методе больше не используется, оптимизации компилятора сами подскажут сборщику, что память можно освободить.

Comment: @tym32167 как минимум, это имеет смыcл, чтобы удалить экземпляр класса: пока есть ссылающиеся на него переменные он будет существовать. А надеяться на сборщик - такое себе, особенно в Юнити, игры на котором вообще славятся своими тормозами и сжиранием памяти как не в себя.

Comment: Что за чушь про "сжирание памяти, как не в себя" и тормоза, как это вообще связано со сборщиком мусора?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker воу воу, полегче :)

Comment: У меня создаётся новая переменная string каждый кадр, так что оставить всё на GC не вариант.

Comment: @Artromskiy исправил ответ.

Comment: `У меня создаётся новая переменная string каждый кадр` думаю, не имеет смысла вызывать это на каждый кадр